# Can possible to use strategy Pattern to apply with save log for application

Tags: c#, asp.net

My question is I wanna apply strategy pattern to save log

[image]

from Image above

I will use replace my class to image

Context = Log Class
Istrategy = ILog

concreteStrategyA = CreateSituation

concreteStrategyB = NameSituation

concreteStrategyC = StatusSituation

[Additional from image]

concreteStrategyD = PriceSituation

concreteStrategyE = DiscountSituation

In ILog have these method
SaveLog(Log log);

each concreteStrategyA,B,C,D,E implement ILog

public class CreateSituation : ILog

{

```
public void SaveLog(Log log)

{

    using(var context = new ProductContext())

    {

      log.Message = "This product is created";

      context.productLog.InsertonSubmit(log);

      context.submitChange();

    }

}
```

}

public class NameSituation : ILog

{

```
public void SaveLog(Log log)

{

    using(var context = new ProductContext())

    {

      log.Message = "this produce has updated name from \"oldProduct\" to \"newProduct\"";

      context.productLog.InsertonSubmit(log);

      context.submitChange();

    }

}
```

}

public class StatusSituation : ILog

{

```
public void SaveLog(Log log)

{

    using(var context = new ProductContext())

    {

      log.Message = "this produce has updated status from \"In stock\" to \"Sold Out\"";

      context.productLog.InsertonSubmit(log);

      context.submitChange();

    }

}
```

}

public class PriceSituation : ILog

{

```
public void SaveLog(Log log)

{

    using(var context = new ProductContext())

    {

      log.Message = "this produce has updated price from $10 to $150";

      context.productLog.InsertonSubmit(log);

      context.submitChange();

    }

}
```

}

public class DiscountSituation : Ilog

{

```
public void SaveLog(Log log)

{

    using(var context = new ProductContext())

    {

      log.Message = "this product has updated discount price from $0 to $20";

      context.productLog.InsertonSubmit(log);

      context.submitChange();

    }

}
```

}

In the future can have more than present situation

and these classes that I show i a good way to solve these problem

Comment: Have you looked at existing logging frameworks such as log4net or the enterprise application block?

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific in what you are asking? I don't understand what the question in your text is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a scenario that could use a strategy pattern.

However, to me it seems to be a just little bit too much to use a completely different logger instance per logging scenario. But without knowing your architecture this is only my personal gut feeling.

As an alternative approach I could imagine implementing a factory for *just assembling the appropriate logging message,* depending on the logging situation.

**[EDIT]**

Additionally I would recommend using some framework like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download.html) that make logging very easy and intuitive. log4net, for example, differentiates between several logging levels like `WARN, INFO, DEBUG, ERROR,`or`FATAL` that allow you to fine-tune your output.

Comment: Thank you for answer. You mean factory for create message, correct?